# JAVA Pass Primitive type as a Reference to function call

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, primitive-types

I am newbie in java. I need to pass primitive type value as a reference in function call.I dont want to return i value from function because it already returns some object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size();) {
  // here it should fetch that object based on i manipulated in function
  Object obj = objects.get(i)
  Object node = someFunction(session,obj,i);
  // push node in nodes array
}
public Object someFunction(Session session,Object obj,int i){
   //manipulate i value based on condition
   if(true){
      i = i + 1;
   }else{
      i = i + 2;
   }
}
```

How i can achieve this as JAVA use pass by value in function call?

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. either way, for each primitive, there is a wrapper class. for int it is Integer. have you checked that out?

Comment: pass primitive as a reference, does this make any sense to you?

Comment: @Eugene Can you add some example?

Comment: examples of what? I don't really understand what you are trying to do to begin with

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, I also tried `Integer` class. but i value is not updating in calling function

Comment: @Eugene I need to change i value in calling function and it should reflect i value in iterator

Comment: The word you are looking for is instance variable

Comment: then return (and assign) the new value, or use an instance variable instead of a local one

Comment: IMO, you have 2 choices: either use an instance variable or you can declare a property within Object returned by somefunction() to store the value of i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of java streams? With streams you can do something like:

```
List<Object> result = objects.stream()
     .filter(object -> {/*add condition here*/})
     .map(object->{/*do something with object that match condition above*/})
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can use this mechanism to collect and process objects based on certain conditions.

If that doesn't help, maybe use an iterator?

```
Iterator<Object> it = objects.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Object node = someFunction(session,it);
}

public Object someFunction(Session session,Iterator i){
   //manipulate i value based on condition
   if(true){
      i.next();
   }else{
      i.next();
      i.next();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In java primitive types always pass by value. To pass by reference you should define a class and put your primitive type in it. If you pass Integer class it doesn't work because this class is immutable and value doesn't change.

Comment: it's *always* pass by value, it's just the value of the reference in case of Objects

Answer (score 2):

You can use a singular array of type `int[]` for a quick solution and increase its internal value. That doesn't change the array itself, only its content.

Comment: thanks, best way to share value as reference